# What's the difference between $bar = boolval($foo) and $bar = (bool) $foo in php?

Tags: php

Same for `intval` / `(int)`, `floatval` / `(float)`, etc.

As far as I can make out, neither changes the original variable, and they both return the casted version.  They appear to be functionally identical.

Are there edge cases where there's a difference?

Any reason to ever use one over the other?

Best practice?

I'm assuming that `(bool)` is "better", as I figure it's probably quicker than a function call that internally probably just does the same thing.  If that's the case though, what's the point of these `boolval`/`intval`/`floatval` functions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the most part they are identical, however there are subtle differences:

- some functions like `intval` accept a second parameter (`$base`), which the cast syntax does not
- a function call has a little more overhead
- functions can be used as callbacks (e.g. `array_map('intval', ..)`), which is not possible with the cast syntax

Answer (score 1):

Using `boolval` vs `(bool)` have diference in cases:
If you needs to return bool and has two ints:

- `return 1 & 1` - return `int`
- `return (bool) 1 & 1` - throw error(using strict_types)
- `return (bool) (1 & 1)` - return bool
- `return boolval(1 & 1)` - return bool

Comment: Woudn't `(bool)(1 & 1)` be also okay? Just parenthesis difference...